# Can I use my local keyboard layout in a remote desktop session?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, keyboard-layout

I use a variant of the Dvorak layout for UK punctuation. When I connect via RDP to one of our administrator boxes the layout is automatically set to US QWERTY.

Can I set RDP to ignore the remote machine's layout and instead use my own?

Comment: By default, the Terminal Services client will map the local keyboard layout to the Terminal Server in the session automatically. If you want to configure it, we could try the link:https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2010/12/27/terminal-server-remote-keyboard-layout/

Answer (score 6):

When invoking RDP, try in Options > Local Resources > Keyboard to set 'Apply windows key combinations' to 'On the local computer'.

In addition, if you control the Terminal Server computer, you may use regedit
to navigate to
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`
and add a DWORD item named `IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout` and give it the value of `1`.

This registry item is described in a very old
[Microsoft Support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322042/input-language-of-terminal-server-client-does-not-match-that-of-termin),
still true today, as a setting for making the Terminal Server retain each user's
keyboard layout, so you only have to set it once.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake on my part. I had expected the language and layout to be the same. I did not notice, that the 2nd language had the same layout installed as the primary language.